# How to run a batch file with a FOR loop with two file names with two parameters?

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am using an `alass` tool to synchronize two subtitles. It is simple to use with one file at a time but I want to use it on multiple files using a loop.

The usage of the tool is like this:

```
alass.bat correct_subtitle.srt incorrect_subtitle.srt output.srt
```

I want to do a simple `for` loop with two parameters with this command:

```
FOR %i IN (*g.srt) DO FOR %n IN (*t.srt) DO alass.bat %i %n %n
```

The script is working but I want the command works one time with the second file not looping the first file with all the second files.

I want the script to do like this:

```
C:\Users\user\Downloads\alass-windows64\alass.bat Batman.Beyond.S01E01.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt Batman.Beyond.S01E01.Rebirth.Part.1.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt Batman.Beyond.S01E01.Rebirth.Part.1.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt 

C:\Users\user\Downloads\alass-windows64\alass.bat Batman.Beyond.S01E02.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt Batman.Beyond.S01E02.Rebirth.Part.2.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt Batman.Beyond.S01E02.Rebirth.Part.2.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt

etc.
```

All the subtitles are in one folder the correct and incorrect subtitles are like this:

```
Correct sub (Batman.Beyond.S01E01.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt) 

incorrect sub (Batman.Beyond.S01E01.Rebirth.Part.1.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt)

Correct sub (Batman.Beyond.S01E02.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt) 

incorrect sub (Batman.Beyond.S01E02.Rebirth.Part.2.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt)
    etc.
```

Comment: Your edit contradicts with the original post. You must clearly specify how the two file names of each pair of files relate, so what part of the file name is the same, and what part not?

Comment: The first three dots match in the correct and incorrect subtitle (Batman.Beyond.S01E01.) and the rest is different.

Comment: So - revision 17 of this saga appears to be where filenames `{1}.SssEee.{2}g.srt` & `{1}.SssEee.{3}t.srt` exist, generate `alass.bat {1}.SssEee.{2}g.srt {1}.SssEee.{3}T.srt {1}.SssEee.{3}T.srt ` - would that be right?

Comment: ...noting that the destination filename is the same as the "incorrect" name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for revision 17 of the question is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.eng.srt /A-D-L /B /ON 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "\.S[0123456789][0123456789]*E[0123456789][0123456789]*\."') do call :ProcessFile "%%I"
endlocal
exit /B

:ProcessFile
echo Correct file:   %1
set "FileNameBegin=%~n1"
:GetMatchingPart
for %%J in ("%FileNameBegin%") do (
    echo %%~xJ| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^\.S[0123456789][0123456789]*E[0123456789][0123456789]*$" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 set "FileNameBegin=%%~nJ" & goto GetMatchingPart
)
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%J in ('dir "%FileNameBegin%.*-FGT.srt" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    echo Incorrect file: "%%J"
    call alass.bat %1 "%%J" "%%J"
)
goto :EOF
```

That code was run on a FAT32 drive with following files in current directory:

```
Batman.Beyond.S01E01.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt
Batman.Beyond.S01E01.Rebirth.Part.1.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt
Batman.Beyond.S01E02.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt
Batman.Beyond.S01E02.Rebirth.Part.2.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt
Exa..mple!.S01E01.anotherName.DTS-FGT.srt
Exa..mple!.S01E01.name.eng.srt
example.S01E02.anotherName-FGT.srt
example.S01E02.name.eng.srt
```

The output without really calling `alass.bat` is:

```
Correct file:   "Batman.Beyond.S01E01.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt"
Incorrect file: "Batman.Beyond.S01E01.Rebirth.Part.1.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt"
Correct file:   "Batman.Beyond.S01E02.1080p.BluRay.Remux.eng.srt"
Incorrect file: "Batman.Beyond.S01E02.Rebirth.Part.2.1080p.BluRay.x264.DTS-FGT.srt"
Correct file:   "Exa..mple!.S01E01.name.eng.srt"
Incorrect file: "Exa..mple!.S01E01.anotherName.DTS-FGT.srt"
Correct file:   "example.S01E02.name.eng.srt"
Incorrect file: "example.S01E02.anotherName-FGT.srt"
```

The main **FOR** loop runs in background one more `cmd.exe` with option `/c` the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

The command **DIR** executed by this second command processor outputs all names of files in current directory matching the wildcard pattern `*.eng.srt`.

This list is redirected to **FINDSTR** which filters the list of file names based on the regular expression `\.S[0123456789][0123456789]*E[0123456789][0123456789]*\.`. So a file name to process must contain a string consisting of

1. a dot
2. case-insensitive the letter `S`
3. one or more digits in range 0 to 9
4. case-insensitive the letter `E`
5. one or more digits in range 0 to 9
6. on more dot.

All the file names ending case-insensitive with `.eng.srt` and matching the regular expression filter criteria are output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDOUT** of background command process and captured by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

The main **FOR** loop processes the list of file names line by line after the started `cmd.exe` process closed itself. File names can contain spaces characters which is the reason for using the option `delims=` to define an empty list of delimiters to turn off the default line splitting behavior on spaces/tabs. File names can start with a semicolon and for that reason the option `eol=|` is used to define the vertical bar as end of line character which no file name can contain ever. So each file name is assigned completely to the specified loop variable `I`

For each file name is called the subroutine `ProcessFile` which first outputs the current file name with correct subtitles.

Next a **FOR** loop is used to remove from the file name the string after last dot which is the file extension according to the definition of Microsoft. The "file extension" string is tested with **FINDSTR** on being the part which is used as identifier and also as separator string between film title and the meta data of the film in file name. If regular expression does not return a positive match on the current "file extension" string, the file name is truncated at end by removing the current "file extension".

Finally after one or more loop runs the beginning of the file name is found consisting of film name with zero or more dots inside and the string matched by the regular expression. So the environment variable `FileNameBegin` is for the four examples:

1. `Batman.Beyond.S01E01`
2. `Batman.Beyond.S01E02`
3. `Exa..mple!.S01E01`
4. `example.S01E02`

That string part is now used to find the matching file with incorrect subtitles ending case-insensitive with the string `-FGT.srt`. That is again done starting one more `cmd.exe` to run **DIR** to find that file.

The usage of the command **DIR** to get a list of matching file names first loaded into memory can be important depending on what `alass.bat` does with the passed file names. That is important especially on FAT file systems like `FAT32` or `exFAT` which do not store the file names in an local specific alphabetic order. The file tables of the file system can be changed on each call of `alass.bat` if this batch file modifies the `srt` files and that is not good on using **FOR** directly to process the files. It can result in skipping some `srt` files or processing some `srt` files more than once or in worst case even in an endless running loop. That is the reason for using **DIR** executed by a command process in background to always get a list of matching file names which does not change anymore while the main **FOR** loop as well as the last **FOR** loop run the commands which perhaps result in changing the file tables of the file system.

That solution is definitely not the fasted possible, but a very fail-safe solution and should work for all film titles and all file systems independent on what `alass.bat` does as long as this batch file does not change the current directory.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: This part of the answer relates to [Revision 17](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73176285/17) of the question.*

I would do it with the following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), assuming that the first `.`-separated parts up to the `S??E??` pattern of the file names of a pair of files are the same:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedexpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."  & rem // (target directory)
set "_PREF=*"       & rem // (prefix of base file names)
set "_MASK=S??E??"  & rem // (middle part of file names without `.`)
set "_FILT=S[0123456789][0123456789]E[0123456789][0123456789]"
set "_SUFF1=*g.srt" & rem // (suffix of 1st file name with extension)
set "_SUFF2=*T.srt" & rem // (suffix of 2nd file name with extension)
set "_TOOL=%~dp0alass.bat"

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop over 1st files:
    for %%I in ("%_PREF%.%_MASK%.%_SUFF1%") do (
        rem // Reset left part of file name, store currently iterated base name:
        set "LEFT=" & set "NAME=%%~nI"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Loop as many times as there are `.`-separated parts in the base name:
        for %%K in ("!NAME:.=" "!") do (
            rem // Do the following only as long as the left part is still not found:
            if not defined LEFT (
                rem // Utilise a `for` loop on the base name to yield `~`-modifiers:
                for %%L in ("!NAME!") do (
                    rem /* Split base name into last part and the rest, the latter
                    rem    of which is going to be used for the next iteration: */
                    endlocal & set "LAST=%%~xL" & set "NAME=%%~nL"
                    rem // Determine whether the last part matches the given pattern:
                    cmd /D /V /C echo(!LAST:~1!| findstr /R /X /I /C:"%_FILT%" > nul && (
                        rem // Match encountered, so store currently processed path:
                        set "LEFT=%%~nxL"
                    )
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Procede further only if a suitable left part of file has been found:
        for %%L in ("!LEFT!") do endlocal & if not "%%~L"=="" (
            rem // Search for respective 2nd file:
            for %%J in ("%%~L.%_SUFF2%") do (
                rem /* Store names of both 1st and 2nd file, then call the sub-script
                rem    utilising the second `%`-expansion established by `call` to
                rem    avoid doubling of `^`-symbols as well as loss of `%`-signs: */
                set "FILE1=%%~I" & set "FILE2=%%~J"
                call "%_TOOL%" "%%FILE1%%" "%%FILE2%%" "%%FILE2%%"
                rem /* Erase 2nd file to prevent reprocessing of same file pairs in
                rem    case of re-execution of this script (remove `ECHO` first!): */
                ECHO del "%%~I"
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The trick herein is to use the `~`-modifiers (namely `~x` and `~n` in particular) of `for`-loop meta-variables to split the file names at `.` from the back within a loop that iterates as many times as there are `.`-separated parts in the base names.

This approach correctly handles file names with characters `!`, `^` and `%`. You can prove that when you create an interim sub-script `alass.bat` with the following contents:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo(%0 %*
endlocal
exit /B
```

In case the tool `alass.bat` overwrites the original `*T.srt` files, which is what I assume, the script deletes the `*g.srt` files (when removing the upper-case `ECHO` in front of the related command) in order not to reprocess the same pair of files upon re-execution of the script.

---

*NOTE: This part of the answer relates to [Revision 9](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73176285/9) of the question.*

I would do it with the following [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedexpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."    & rem // (target directory)
set "_SUFF1=g"        & rem // (suffix for base names of 1st files)
set "_SUFF2=T"        & rem // (suffix for base names of 2nd files)
set "_MASK=*%_SUFF1%" & rem // (name search pattern for 1st files)
set "_EXT=.srt"       & rem // (extensions for 1st and 2nd files)

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Loop over 1st files:
    for %%I in ("%_MASK%%_EXT%") do (
        rem // Store base name of currently iterated 1st file:
        set "NAME=%%~nI"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Build base name of respective 2nd file; temporarily appending `|` to the
        rem    name (which cannot occur in a file name) ensures to just replace the very
        rem    last occurrence of the suffix: */
        set "REPL=!NAME!|" & set "REPL=!REPL:%_SUFF1%|=%_SUFF2%!"
        rem // Skip in case there is no respective 2nd file:
        if exist "!REPL!!_EXT!" (
            rem /* Call sub-script with 1st and 2nd file as input files and 2nd one also
            rem    as output file, preventing delayed expansion but utilising the second
            rem    `%`-expansion phase established by `call` in order to avoid doubling
            rem    of `^`-symbols as well as loss of `%`-signs: */
            REM call "%~dp0alass.bat" "!NAME!!_EXT!" "!REPL!!_EXT!" "!REPL!!_EXT!"
            call "%~dp0alass.bat" "%%NAME%%%%_EXT%%" "%%REPL%%%%_EXT%%" "%%REPL%%%%_EXT%%"
            rem /* Erase 2nd file to prevent reprocessing of same file pairs in case of
            rem    re-execution of the script: */
            ECHO del "!NAME!!_EXT!"
        )
        endlocal
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach correctly handles file names with characters `!`, `^` and `%`. You can prove that when you create an interim sub-script `alass.bat` with the following contents:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo(%0 %*
endlocal
exit /B
```

If you used the commented-out `call` command line (with the upper-case `REM` in front), `^`-symbols would become doubled and `%`-signs would become lost.

In case the tool `alass.bat` (which is assumed to reside in the same location as this script) overwrites the original `*T.srt` files, which is what I assume, the script deletes the `*g.srt` files (when removing the upper-case `ECHO` in front of the related command) in order not to reprocess the same pair of files upon re-execution of the script.

Comment: Thank you for your support aschipfl, can you clarify what I should put in these two sets: ("_PREF=*") & ("_MASK=S??E??")?

Comment: You're welcome! `_MASK` represents the `.`-separated portion of the file names until which the file pairs are determined (which is `S??E??` in your examples, with `??` representing numbers); `_PREF` represents a pattern for what lies before; since ther is literally averything allowed, I set it to `*`. In order words, the script with these variables set as stated work on your example files. Do you have files that cause issues with my script?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** *New better version*

I added a new version that I think is the fastest and most convenient way to solve this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process "correct" files with eng.srt extension
for %%i in (*.eng.srt) do (
   echo   Correct sub: %%i
   set "correct=%%i"

   rem Search for the prefix of this file
   set "name="
   set "prefix="
   for %%k in ("!correct:.=" "!") do if not defined prefix (
      set "part=%%~k"
      set "name=!name!.!part!"

      rem Check if this part have the "S##E##" end of prefix format
      if "!part:~0,1!!part:~3,1!!part:~6!" equ "SE" (   rem "S__E__" letters and length match
         set /A "S=E=0, S=1!part:~1,2!-100, E=1!part:~4,2!-100" 2>nul
         if !S! gtr 0 if !E! gtr 0 (   rem Both ## numbers match: end of prefix found

            rem Process the companion "incorrect" *FGT.srt file
            set "prefix=!name:~1!"
            set "name="
            for %%n in (!prefix!.*FGT.srt) do (
               echo Incorrect sub: %%n
               echo/
               REM call alass.bat %%i %%n %%n
               set "name=%%n"
            )
            if not defined name (
               echo Warning: Incorrect sub not found
               echo/
            )

         )
      )

   )
   if not defined prefix (
      echo Warning: Bad filename format
      echo/
   )

)
```

---

**EDIT**: *New version for the last OP´s revision*

This Batch file should solve this question:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Count files with same prefix
for %%a in (*.srt) do (
   set "name=%%a"
   set "prefix="
   for %%b in ("!name:.=" "!") do (
      set "prefix=!prefix!%%~b."
      set /A "count[!prefix:-=_!]+=1"
   )
)

rem Process pairs of files
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   if %%b equ 2 (
      set "right="
      for %%c in ("%%a*.srt") do (
         if not defined right (
            set "right=%%c"
         ) else (
            set "wrong=%%c"
         )
      )
      call alass.bat !right! !wrong! !wrong!
   )
)
```

---

Accordingly to your description: *"The files have different names like this: Correct sub (example.S01E01.name.ybg.srt). Incorrect sub (differentExample.S01E01.anotherName.wrt.srt)."* That is: correct and incorrect names of the same set have the second dot-separated token the same, like `S01E01` or `S01E02` in the examples shown.

The Batch file below solve *such* problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%i in (*g.srt) do for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%k in ("%%i") do (
   for %%n in (*.%%k.*t.srt) do (
      call alass.bat %%i %%n %%n
   )
)
```

Comment: Working perfectly, thank you Aacini.

Comment: How can I use the batch with another series, what should I change?

Comment: If for "another series" you mean different endings of the file names, just change the file name wildcard patterns `*.eng.srt` and `*FGT.srt` in the two `for` loops as long as the file names still contain a matching part like `.S01E01.`  I wrote a new version of the program that IMHO is the fastest way to solve this problem. I invite you to test it and post the results of a timing test, if possible... **`;)`**

Comment: Ok I test the new version but didn't work for me, I only change the endings of the file names and remove the REM before the call alass.bat and replace the alass with the actual patch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach to v17

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the source directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"

FOR %%s IN (0 1) DO FOR /L %%t IN (0 1 9) DO FOR %%e IN (0 1) DO FOR /L %%f IN (0 1 9) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%o IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.S%%s%%tE%%e%%f.*T.srt" 2^>nul'
 ) DO (
  SET "name=%%~no"
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=/" %%p IN ("!name:.S%%s%%tE%%e%%f.=/!") DO (
   FOR %%b IN ("%sourcedir%\%%p.S%%s%%tE%%e%%f.*g.srt") do ECHO CALL alass.bat  "%%~fb" "%%~fo" "%sourcedir%\%%p.S%%s%%tE%%e%%f.%%q.srt"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

As ever, the generated lines are simply `echo`ed.

Essentially, for each S and E 00..19, locate the "T" file (otherwise, no point) split the name on the `.SssEee.` string and find the {1}.SssEee.*g.srt file

mix and match the parts.

...but I still have problems understanding the destination filename...

Comment: Working perfectly, I removed the ECHO before the CALL alass.bat

Comment: Do you mean the output subtitle? it will overwrite the incorrect sub.